# SignalR-Objc - Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

Following the [How To Get Started](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC#how-to-get-started) section for [SignalR-ObjC](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC) repo, I'm getting the following error when I build the `SignalR.Samples.iOS` project:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SRWebSocket", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libSignalR.Client.iOS.a(SRWebSocketTransport.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SRWebSocketConnectionInfo, _OBJC_CLASS_$_SRWebSocketTransport )
>     "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SRHTTPRequestOperation in libSignalR.Client.iOS.a(SRServerSentEventsTransport.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONResponseSerializer", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libSignalR.Client.iOS.a(SRHttpBasedTransport.o)
>         objc-class-ref in libSignalR.Client.iOS.a(SRServerSentEventsTransport.o)
>         objc-class-ref in libSignalR.Client.iOS.a(SRLongPollingTransport.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libSignalR.Client.iOS.a(SRHttpBasedTransport.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_SRHTTPRequestOperation in libSignalR.Client.iOS.a(SRServerSentEventsTransport.o)
>         objc-class-ref in libSignalR.Client.iOS.a(SRLongPollingTransport.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

To resolve this issue I have also checked this links :

- [Linker error comes while running as well as testing the Xcode workspace after updating KIF framework via cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782801/linker-error-comes-while-running-as-well-as-testing-the-xcode-workspace-after-up/22005367#22005367)
- [Linker error comes while running as well as testing the Xcode workspace after updating KIF framework via cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782801/linker-error-comes-while-running-as-well-as-testing-the-xcode-workspace-after-up).

But still the issue persists.
How can I correct the following issue? (I am using XCode 6.1)

Comment: u check with device or simulator

Comment: the message clearly says the _simulator_ is the non-supported architecture in your case.

Comment: Suhail & holex -- I am using device iPhone5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The readme and sample are out of date with latest (as of this writing) Cocoapods/XCode (XCode 6.1/Yosemite). There are bunch of steps to clean all this up:

- comment (or fix) `_cancelled` in `AFURLConnectionOperation.m` to fix the semantic issue error
- Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19477239/244353), do not override "Other Linker Flags". If it is bold, select it and press backspace, it should be back to its normal state. For me, it was -ObjC which I cleared.
- Clear out [`OTHER_LD_FLAGS`](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/826): take out -l"icucore" from `Pods.SignalR.Client.iOS.debug.xcconfig` (and/or `...release.xcconfig` depending on what mode you're building against)
- Clean > Build

Answer (score 1):

In my case I update pods File as below

**platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.4'**

then I installed the dependencies in my project:

**$ pod install**

And at last follow the step suggested by @ Mrchief and it's work for me.